# Triangulation of 3D objects in Matlab

Tags: matlab, triangulation, delaunay

I need to make a surface triangulation of stones (aggregates) point cloud in Matlab. For this I have `x,y,z` in Cartesian coordinate system.

For the simplicity I have started with spherical object.

```
DT = delaunayTriangulation(x,y,z);
figure
trisurf(DT.ConnectivityList,DT.Points(:,1),DT.Points(:,2),DT.Points(:,3), ...
       'FaceColor','cyan','FaceAlpha', 0.8);
```

Run the code and result is:
[Triangulation of Spherical Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXHEc.png)

It makes triangles inside the sphere too. Connecting one point to another one in opposite or somewhere else.

Also, `delaunayTriangulation()` function triangulates for idealized surfaces and do not works for sensitive surfaces. Think about the surface of stone, there are a lot of irregularity on it.

Then I have tried `DelaunayTri()` function. It worked for sphere object, triangulated only surface. But when tried more complex (stone) shape, the function just idealized the shape and not considered all protrusions (irregularity) of stone.

```
tri = DelaunayTri(x,y,z);
[FBtri,FBpoints] = freeBoundary(tri);

figure
trisurf(FBtri,FBpoints(:,1),FBpoints(:,2),FBpoints(:,3), ...
       'FaceColor','cyan','FaceAlpha', 0.8);
```

When `freeBoundary()` function removed from above code, result is same (idealized) and triangulation made inside the object, which is not acceptable.

Finally, I have used the `delaunay()` function. Which is even not correctly triangulated the sphere.

```
tri = delaunay(x,y,z);
figure
trisurf(tri,x,y,z,'FaceColor','cyan','FaceAlpha', 0.8);
```

Question: With which function and how (please detailed) can I make the detailed 3D triangulation of any shaped stone surface? What was my mistakes above codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the pure `delaunay`-based methods you tried will do what you want -- they all tessellate the full convex-hull of the input, not just the surface.

Reconstructing general surfaces from point-clouds is not a straight-forward task. I don't believe it can be done directly using a built-in `MATLAB` function.

You may wish to look into other options, such as the [surface-reconstruction](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Poisson_surface_reconstruction_3/) tools provided by CGAL.